# alter table (mysql) adding column with default value of space (' ')

Tags: mysql, default-value

On my Mac, using  5.5.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
alter table foobaz  add column (
extendedTitle varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
clasindxIndent int,
spacedash1 enum (' ', '-', '1') default ' ',
plusSubs enum (' ', '+') default ' ');
```

works perfectly. On my Debian server using 5.1.49-3-log (Debian), it fails with

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'spacedash1'
```

I don't understand the error, or why it works on my Mac and not on my server. Any hints or pointers greatly appreciated.

Pat

Comment: I suggest you change these Enums to `CHAR(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the rules have changed, or somebody missed something in compiler builds.

According to the [MySQL Documentation on ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html)

> For example, a column specified as ENUM('one', 'two', 'three') can have any of the values shown here. The index of each value is also shown.
>
> Value   Index
>
> NULL    NULL
>
> ''      0
>
> 'one'   1
>
> 'two'   2
>
> 'three' 3
>
> An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements.
>
> Trailing spaces are automatically deleted from ENUM member values in
>   the table definition when a table is created.

You are using MySQL 5.1.49. That build probably errors out on seeing a one-character string with a blank.

MySQL 5.5 probably removes trailing spaces leaving an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. And I'll look for a 5.5 to upgrade to on the server